# How to pipe to Next.js 13 api response?

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js, fetch-api, next.js13

Earlier, I was able to pipe the response of another api call to Next.js api response as follows

```
export default async function (req, res) {
    // prevent same site/ obfuscate original API
    // some logic here 
    fetch(req.body.url).then(r => {
      r.body.pipe(res);
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
      res.status(500).send("Invalid Url");
    })
}
```

It worked fine. But now the `response.body` from fetch API does not have `pipe` method. Rather, it has `pipeTo` and `pipeThrough` methods. And the Next.js `res:NextApiResponse`, is not assignable to `WritableStream`.

I also tried creating `blob` (`await r.blob()`) and using `res.send(blob)` and `res.send(blob.strem())`. It seems to work at first but the data received by front end is not proper (Basically `fetch().then((res) => res.blob()).then((blob) => URL.createObjectURL(blob)))` will give corrupt result).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the trick that worked like a charm!

```
const https = require("https");

export default async function handler(req, res) {
   try {
      const url = `your-url`;
      res.status(200);
      https.get(url, (response) => {
        response.pipe(res);
        response.on("finish", res.end);
      });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      res.status(500).send("Invalid Url");
    }
}
```

### Update

The above trick works great for some simple cases but fails when there are redirects.

The Readable API works better than this as suggested by Klesum

```
import { Readable } from 'node:stream';

export default async function (req, res) {
    fetch(req.body.url).then(r => {
      Readable.fromWeb(r.body).pipe(res);
    })
}
```

TypeScript complains about this, but you can ignore ts warnings for that line `// @ts-ignore` and it would work fine.

Comment: This solution won't follow redirects though.

Answer (score 2):

There exists the [Readable.fromWeb()](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#streamreadablefromwebreadablestream-options) experimental API that transforms `fetch()` [ReadableStream](https://nodejs.org/api/webstreams.html#class-readablestream) into [nodejs stream](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#class-streamreadable). Seems to work in node v18.14.0.

```js
import { Readable } from 'node:stream';

export default async function (req, res) {
    // prevent same site/ obfuscate original API
    // some logic here 
    fetch(req.body.url).then(r => {
      Readable.fromWeb(r.body).pipe(res);
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
      res.status(500).send("Invalid Url");
    })
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works great. Can you suggest something similar that can work with youtube videos?

Comment: Hm, I would think that for normal video links fetched by `fetch` it would work same way through `Readable.fromWeb(r.body).pipe(res)`, though I think youtube probably has some protection from directly downloading their videos, otherwise there would not be need for tools like [youtube-dl](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl).