# how to use busboy with Nextjs 13 api POST

Tags: next.js, busboy

I want to create Nextjs api route which allow to upload file from client and save file locally using busboy with stream to receiving large file.

But the problem is NextJs show me an error
`req.pipe is not a function`

how to handle this situation?

```js
export async function POST(req, { params }){


    const bb = busboy({ 
        headers: {
            ...req.headers,
            'content-type': req.headers.get('Content-type')
        }
     })

     bb.on('file', (name, stream, info) => {
        console.log('onfile')
        // handle file stream with fs
     })

     req.pipe(bb) // error occured from here

   
    return NextResponse.json({ success: true })
}
```

I found a solution which use [Readable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74699607/how-to-pipe-to-next-js-13-api-response#:%7E:text=import%20%7B%20Readable%20%7D%20from%20%27node%3Astream%27%3B%0A%0Aexport%20default%20async%20function%20(req%2C%20res)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20fetch(req.body.url).then(r%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20Readable.fromWeb(r.body).pipe(res)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%0A%7D) from stack overflow

But the problem is it is not working as stream
and `Readable.fromWeb(req.body)` read all things from body and pipe to busboy

```js
import { Readable } from 'node:stream';
export async function POST(req, { params }){
    const bb = busboy({ 
        headers: {
            ...req.headers,
            'content-type': req.headers.get('Content-type')
        }
     })

     bb.on('file', (name, stream, info) => {
        console.log('onfile')
     })


     Readable.fromWeb(req.body).pipe(bb); // by using Readable

    return NextResponse.json({ success: true })
}
```